# Is SQLCipher needed anymore?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios9, sqlcipher

Now that with iOS 8.3 and above, iOS doesn't allow application folder access of any app which doesn't support iTunes File sharing, is it really necessary to use SQLCipher or for that matter any sort of encryption for the data, considering the performance impact SQLCipher has. Also since iOS 10 just few months away, there is a very high possibility that we can completely ditch iOS 8 support in our apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is SQLCipher needed anymore?

Well, I suppose this question should be asked on a case-by-case basis.  Even with the permission changes, some directories are still visible to the end user out-of-the box.  See [iOS 8.3 File Sharing](http://support.digidna.net/hc/en-us/articles/206140907-iOS-8-3-File-Sharing).

> is it really necessary to use SQLCipher or for that matter any sort of encryption for the data

It depends on what you're storing.  If you are storing sensitive information like private keys, bank accounts or personal information, I would continue to secure your data as best as possible.  Any use with a jailbroken device could potentially be able to reach into your unencrypted database on iOS 8.3 and above, or hook into your database handle code and manually open the database to retrieve the information.

Comment: But as i said, in a couple of months developers will start ditching iOS 8 and when that happens we dont need to worry about 8.3 anymore.